# How to update facebook shared image without changing image file name

Tags: facebook, image, caching, share

I have a webpage in my site that I want user to share on FB. I have a meta og tag: "og:image" content="/images/xxx.png"

I have uploaded a new updated image several times (same file name) but when i share the page it still display the old image.

I have tried "/images/xxx.png?123", but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To update OG properties of your URL use debugger tool.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug